# Arch Linux 2014.04 64bit and connectivity problem during installation

Tags: arch-linux, realtek

I downloaded the latest ISO image from the Arch Linux website and burned the .iso file on an USB drive with some of the many tools you can find on the web.

Once I get on the shell screen I try to test my connectivity to the internet, but it doesn't work. My Ethernet card is correctly detected (I can see it if I do ifconfig) and is also in an "up" state.

I already tried to manually set the configuration using *ethtool* but with no luck. Also, I already tried re-activating the DHCP service but still no luck. I tried to bring the interface up/down and manually configure an IP address but it still doesn't work.

I searched in dmesg and as far as I can tell the r8xxx module of the kernel for my realtek card is loaded correctly.

I am really running out of options. The most frustrating thing is that only with Arch Linux I have this problem. ALL the other distros run just fine, getting an IP address from DHCP with no intervention from myself what-so-ever, so it's not a compatibility problem here but a configuration one.

I also noted that the dropped packets count increases as time goes by.

Here is some output from the commands:

```
ping 8.8.8.8
connect: Network is unreachable

ethtool enp7s1
Settings for enp7s1:
    Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                         100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                         1000baseT/Full 
    Link partner advertised pause frame use: No
    Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: MII
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: g
    Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                   drv probe ifdown ifup
    Link detected: yes

ifconfig
enp7s1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::16da:e9ff:fe21:fdbf  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 14:da:e9:21:fd:bf  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 943  bytes 64724 (63.2 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 117  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 17  bytes 2933 (2.8 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp7s1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 14:da:e9:21:fd:bf brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

dmesg | grep r8169

[    2.742091] r8169 Gigabit Ethernet driver 2.3LK-NAPI loaded
[    2.742154] r8169 0000:07:01.0 (unregistered net_device): not PCI Express
[    2.742666] r8169 0000:07:01.0 eth0: RTL8169sc/8110sc at 0xffffc9000181e000, 14:da:e9:21:fd:bf, XID 18000000 IRQ 19
[    2.742668] r8169 0000:07:01.0 eth0: jumbo features [frames: 7152 bytes, tx checksumming: ok]
[    9.037449] r8169 0000:07:01.0 enp7s1: link down
[    9.037502] r8169 0000:07:01.0 enp7s1: link down
[   11.874477] r8169 0000:07:01.0 enp7s1: link up

route 

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface



sudo systemctl status dhcpcd
● dhcpcd.service - dhcpcd on all interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service; disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

I also tried running simply "dhcpd" and it seemed to work (he saw my router and leased me an IP address) but at some point it timed out and didn't get an IP.

Comment: "but it doesn't work"? how did you test? What you did with ethtool (with exact commands) that didn't work?

Comment: *Ethtool -s enp7s1 speed 1000 duplex full* And it didn't give any errors. Tried to ping google dns with no luck.

Comment: edit your question and include the output of ping, and ethtool

Comment: If you're using a recent verion of Arch you shouldn't be using ifconfig. Try ip link set eth0 up where eth0 is the name of your device and start the dhcpd service.  The wiki has all of this information readily available along with common problems.

Comment: Already tried... didn't work.

Comment: what's the output from? sudo systemctl status dhcpcd

Comment: sudo systemctl start dhcpcd should start up dhcpcd.  systemctl enable dhcpcd will tell it to run every time the computer starts. You may need to specify dhcpcd@enp7s1.service or something similliar if it givese you a problem.

Comment: Already tried what you advice. Didn't work.

Comment: Sorry about the repetition It's always good to verify. I'm away from my Arch box, when I get back I'll look into how I fixed mine. But you'll almost certainly get better and quicker help from the forums or the IRC.

Comment: Yeah, posted also on the Arch forums. I hope I can get past this problem. If anything else, because I'd like to know WHY it's behaving like this when no other distro does. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem.
Apparently there is a problem between my router (Fritz Box) and the dhcp version on Archlinux. They don't interact correctly.
To make it possible to have an internet connection, go into your Fritz Box settings and delete the IP related to your machine. Once you do this the router will give out IP's like it should.
The problems lies with the "Assign the same IP to this machine" option in the FritzBox settings. Apparently, when you select this option the DHCP on Arch goes crazy. Simply disable it, go back to your PC and get an address and the you can re-enable it without problems.
Thank you anyways for your help.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just had the same problem but would have never thought about the router: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126694/enabling-wired-internet-connection-with-dhcp-during-arch-linux-installation/126709

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is caused by a Windows/Arch Linux dual-boot setup. The Windows and Arch Linux DHCP clients identify the PC in a different way, so the router thinks they are not one and the same. Setting **clientid** instead of **duid** in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` fixed this for me (learned from [this forum topic](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1247523)). I also have a Fritz Box ADSL modem/router (Fon WLAN 7113).

With **duid** set, the Fritz Box web interface listed my PC using the network interface name (*enp2s0*) instead of the hostname. Not sure if this is relevant, but it did strike me as odd.

Comment: The dhcp client has to be killed with `dhcpcd -k` and restarted with `dhcpcd` after the config has been changed. IMO this is the easiest solution to the problem.