# Arch Linux installation - no internet connection and can't ping gateway

Tags: networking, arch-linux, system-installation

I'm doing a clean install of 32-bit Arch Linux from a CD on a very old Panasonic CF-29 Toughbook. Trying to connect to the Internet from the terminal on the installation ISO is not working. I'm using an Ethernet cable. My interface is called `enp2s2`:

```
# ip link
1: lo: ...
2: enp2s: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq-codel state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:0b:97:2b:e7:2e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

When trying to ping Google:

```
# ping -c 3 www.google.com
ping: www.google.com: Name or service not known
```

And my gateway:

```
# ping 192.168.1.1
connect: Network is unreachable
```

The same happens with 8.8.8.8.

I tried to add a gateway:

```
# route add default gw 192.168.1.1
SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable
```

And dhcpcd gets as far as:

```
# dhcpcd enp2s2
DUID 00:01:00:01:1f:8a:90:98:00:0b:97:2b:e7:2e
enp2s2: IAID 97:2b:e7:2e
enp2s2: soliciting an IPv6 router
enp2s2: soliciting a DHCP lease
enp2s2: no IPv6 routers available
timed out
dhcpcd exited
```

I have tried these two:

```
# ip link set enp2s2 up
# systemctl enable dhcpcd@enp2s2.service
```

Neither have any effect.

Before reading [Enabling wired internet connection with dhcp during Arch Linux Installation?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/126694) I hadn't considered it being a router problem but how likely is this?

My `netconfig` file  is as follows:

```
udp        tpi_clts       v    inet        udp   -    - 
tcp        tpi_cots_ord   v    inet        tcp   -    -
udp6       tpi_clts       v    inet6       udp   -    -
tcp6       tpi_cots_ord   v    inet6       tcp   -    -
rawip      tpi_raw        -    inet         -    -    -
local      tpi_cots_ord   -    loopback     -    -    -
unix       tpi_cots_ord   -    loopback     -    -    -
```

Comment: Have you looked at ifconfig and your /etc/network config? You may have to manually make the change in /etc/network.

Comment: I've posted my netconfig file above, but I don't see what inside it should be changed for this. What do you think?

Comment: Post output from `ip addr` and `ip route` commands ...

Answer (score 0):

dhcpcd enps2s2 get this output

```
# dhcpcd enp2s2
DUID 00:01:00:01:1f:8a:90:98:00:0b:97:2b:e7:2e
enp2s2: IAID 97:2b:e7:2e
enp2s2: soliciting an IPv6 router
enp2s2: soliciting a DHCP lease
enp2s2: no IPv6 routers available
timed out
dhcpcd exited
```

From this output, we can know that You don't have DHCP service in your network. So You Don't have IP address in your device

You can assing Manually by using this command

```
# ip link set eth0 up
# ip addr add 192.168.1.2/24 broadcast 192.168.1.255 dev eth0
# ip route add default via 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it still doesn't work...trying to ping 192.168.1.1 just says `From 192.168.1.118 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable` It appears the ip address added (192.168.1.2) is now secondary.